# Path-based authorization for microservices in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, authorization, kubernetes-ingress

I am tasked with migrating AWS lambda microservices to Kubernetes. For simplicity, there are two service endpoints: `/admin` and `/user` where you can GET or POST a request to get something done.

You have to be in `admin` group (defined in an external authZ provider) to hit `/admin` endpoint, or otherwise, you get 401. You have to be in `user` group to have access to `/user` endpoint.

I will have each endpoint exposed as a service running in a docker container. The question is - what is the correct way to add routing and path-based authorization in Kubernetes?

Like, if I go to `/admin` in the browser, I need Kubernetes to check if I am in `admin` group and then route me to `admin` service; otherwise, it should return 401.

I can write this router myself, but I want to check if there is a built-in solution in Kubernetes for that.

Answer (score 1):

> check if there is a built-in solution in Kubernetes

Nope, there's no built-in solution for L7 network policies. [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) in Kubernetes are at L4 level, so things like rate limiting, path based firewall rules etc are not possible. Although you could look into a Service Mesh, like [Linkerd](https://linkerd.io/), [Istio](https://istio.io/) or even using a different CNI plugin based on `eBPF` such as [Cilium](https://cilium.io/blog/2018/09/19/kubernetes-network-policies/).

Cilium has a CRD `CiliumNetworkPolicy` which would help you with your usecase. You can put any proxy like Nginx/Caddy/HAProxy in front of it or an API Gateway like Kong, if you want to offload the authentication/authorization process. You can apply the following network policy, which would restrict the `/admin` endpoint on any pod with label `app: customapp` and would only allow it from a pod with label `app: proxyapp`.

```
apiVersion: "cilium.io/v2"
kind: CiliumNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: "allow-from-proxy"
specs:
  - endpointSelector:
      matchLabels:
        app: customapp
    ingress:
    - fromEndpoints:
      - matchLabels:
          app: proxyapp
      toPorts:
      - ports:
        - port: "8080"
          protocol: "TCP"
        rules:
          http:
          - method: "GET"
            path: "/admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explore istio's traffic management. They provide routing based on user identity (https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/#route-based-on-user-identity). But they do this by finding the user from request header. If you have an admin group then not sure whether this can be used as is.

Sample virtual service:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: reviews
  ...
spec:
  hosts:
  - reviews
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        end-user:
          exact: jason
    route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v2
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v1
```

The above service can be accessed from outside the cluster using istio gateway.