# Kubernetes - Restrict access to private URIs in application

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have an application running as a pod in a kubernetes cluster. Application has multiple endpoints such as /app /healthcheck etc.

I want to expose /app endpoint to users-group-1.
And both /app and /healthcheck endpoints to users-group-2.

How do we configure such restriction?

I can add-in ingress-controller if needed, even though system has just one cluster with one service.

Thanks.

Comment: does the solution of Ermuz Hossain help you?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak no. I believe the doc referred talks about allowing/denying at apiGroups not for user-groups.

Comment: nonResourceURLs don't belong to any specific APIGroup or namespaces, they are cluster-wide.
You mixed-up things probably,  granting permissions to actors (users, group, ServiceAccount) is realized through Role/ClusterRole binding, not in Role/ClusterRole definitions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to implement authorization and authentication (including restrictions) based on the URL to the client application running in Kubernetes using the mechanism built into Kubernetes i.e. RBAC.

This type of process should be transferred to a dedicated tool such as [Keycloack](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/). You can find a guide about [Authorization Services](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/). I have found also a [tutorial](https://www.openshift.com/blog/adding-authentication-to-your-kubernetes-web-applications-with-keycloak) for adding authentication to your Kubernetes Web applications with Keycloak.

You can also see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60270915/path-based-authorization-for-microservices-in-kubernetes). The answer will confirm that it has built-in tools in kubernetes to achieve your goal. Instead, you will find information on how you can use [istio for this purpose](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/#route-based-on-user-identity).

Answer (score 0):

You can use RBAC to restrict the endpoints to a certain group using `nonResourceURLs` field. Here, is an example:

```
rules:
- nonResourceURLs: ["/app", "/healthcheck/*"]
  verbs: ["get", "post"]
```

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-examples